# how to display the total count of individual words from a list

Tags: sas, using

In the data for 10000 item_ids, the item description is given so how to count the frequency of individual word in the item description column, for a particular item_id, where the item_id are repeating, using SAS (without using array).

Goal is to identify the keywords for a particular item_id.

Answer (score 2):

Following approach leverage Proc Freq to get 'keyword' distribution.

```
data have;
infile cards truncover;
input id var $ 100.;
cards;
1 This is test test
2 failed
1 be test
2 failed is
3 success
3 success ok
;

/*This is to break down the description into single word*/
data want;
set have;
do _n_=1 to countw(var);
new_var=scan(var,_n_);
output;
end;
run;

/*This is to give you words freq by id*/

ods output list=mylist (keep=id new_var frequency);
PROC FREQ DATA = want
    ORDER=FREQ
;
    TABLES id * new_var /
        NOCOL
        NOPERCENT
        NOCUM
        SCORES=TABLE
        LIST
        ALPHA=0.05;
RUN; QUIT;
ods _all_ close;
ods listing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are used to read across multiple columns, so aren't of any particular use here.  This does sound a bit like a homework question and you should really show some attempt that you've made.  However, this is not an easy problem to solve, so I will post a solution.

My thoughts on how to approach this are :

1. Sort the data by item_id
2. For every item_id, scan through each word and check if it already exists for that item_id. If so then go to the next word, otherwise add the word to the unique list and increment the counter by 1
3. When the last of the current item_id's is processed, output the unique word list and count

I've hopefully commented the code below sufficiently for you to follow what's going on, if not then look up the particular function or statement online.

```
/* create dummy dataset */
data have;
input item_id item_desc $30.;
datalines;
1   this is one
1   this is two
2   how many words are here
2   not many
3   random selection
;
run;

/* sort dataset if necessary */
proc sort data=have;
by item_id;
run;

/* extract unique words from description */
data want;
set have;
by item_id;
retain unique_words unique_count; /* retain value from previous row */
length unique_words $200; /* set length for unique word list */
if first.item_id then do; /* reset unique word list and count when item_id changes */
    call missing(unique_words);
    unique_count = 0;
    end;
do i = 1 by 1 while(scan(item_desc,i) ne ''); /* scan each word in description until the end */
    if indexw(unique_words,scan(item_desc,i),'|') > 0 then continue; /* check if word already exists in unique list, if so then go to next word */
    else do;
        call catx('|',unique_words,scan(item_desc,i)); /* add to list of unique words, separated by | */
        unique_count+1; /* count number of unique words */
        end;
end;
drop item_desc i; /* drop unwanted columns */
if last.item_id then output; /* output id, unique word list and count when last id */
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, I have run the code given above and got the unique count of the words but my objective didn't get solve, I want the total individual count (frequency) of the words used in the item_descr for all particular item_id.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question.  The solution from @Haikuo will provide what you want

Comment: @Anurag It's generally better to include a sample of the input and output in the question to avoid such misunderstandings

Comment: data: Item_id  Item_descr
         00123  Chick shampoo of 100gm.
         00112  Dettol soap with 250gm.
         08897  Apolo tyers with 20mm width
         00123  Shampoo 200gm of Chick
         00112  300gm soap of dettol with extra protection,
So as per the above data I have to calculate the count of words for each unique item_id in the respective item_descr column. If the words are repeating for the same item_id than the count should get increase, so that on the basis of count of words we can identify the top 10 high frequency words to decide the KEYWORD for that  particular item_id